# Shutdown system tray icon on PyGObject

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk, pygobject

My vision of the program: icon in tray, left click on icon opens a window with shutdown, reboot, etc. buttons.

The new Gnome specification advises to use notifications instead.

> StatusIcon >! (Deprecated since version 3.14: Use notifications)

Unfortunately, I didn't find how [Notify.Notification](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Notify-0.7/classes/Notification.html) can be displayed in the tray. The only thing that I found is [AppIndicator3.Indicator](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/AppIndicator3-0.1/classes/Indicator.html), but its constructor can only take a Gtk.Menu, which is unsuitable.

Which classes may I use?

Comment: Thank you, Frederic, next time I will be more attentive to grammar

Comment: Unfortunately no one has written an alternative to GtkStatusIcon yet. While it may be deprecated, you can still use it if you really want, but you'll have to investigate recreating it yourself if you need a status icon that isn't restricted to the limitations of the notifications API and really don't want to use deprecated APIs.

Comment: @andlabs, your comment save many hours of my time, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used GtkStatusIcon due to comments